# How does the kernel use task_struct?

Tags: c, linux, process, linux-kernel, kernel

I am a student doing research involving Linux processes, and I need to learn more about them to proceed with my experiment. In reading a couple books and things online, I've come across `task_struct`, which I'm not sure I'm understanding fully, and would like confirmation/correction onto my existing thought.

From what I think I've understood, `task_struct` is the C structure that acts as the process descriptor, holding everything the kernel might need to know about a processes. At the end of the process kernel stack lives another struct, `thread_info`, which has a pointer to the processes `task_struct`.

Another question: how does one access the `task_struct` of a process? Is there a calculation to find the location of it's `thread_info`? Is there a macro/function within the kernel?

Comment: You probably will find this [FAQ about 'current' macro](https://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/current) useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the `task_struct` structure contains all the information about a process. You can obtain a pointer to the structure that describes the current process using the `current` macro as follows:

```
struct task_struct *p = current;
```

If you want to get the structure that describes a process given a `pid`, you can use the `find_task_by_vpid` function as follows:

```
read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
p = find_task_by_vpid(pid);
if (p) get_task_struct(p);
read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
if (p == NULL) {
    // Task not found.
}

// Later, once you're finished with the task, execute:
put_task_struct(p);
```

Finally, if you want to iterate over all processes, you can use `for_each_process` as follows:

```
read_lock(&tasklist_lock);
for_each_process(p) {
    // p is a pointer to a task_struct instance.
}
read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
```

If you want to an exclusive access to the task list to be able to make changes to one or more fields in the structure, `write_lock_irqsave` must be used instead of `read_lock`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try answer second question.

On the top of each process kernel stack there is a structure *thread_info*.

To get address of/pointer to *thread_info*, different architectures have different solutions, but on x86 it looks something like this:

To get pointer to *thread_info* just mask 13 bits of the stack pointer value:

```
movl $0xFFFFE000, %eax
andl %esp, %eax
```

Now we have pointer, and this structure has pointer for *task_struct* structure.

To get it, there is a *current* macro, which looks something like this:

`#define current (current_thread_info()->task)`

and it gives you pointer (address of) *task_struct*

Comment: And in arm64 case, `current` is defined as `task_struct *get_current()` and get_current returns sp_el0 register. because sp_el0 is not used in OS, for fast access they use sp_el0 (stack pointer for exception level 0(user level)) for the task_struct pointer.